# How to get the key value of HASHMAP which resides on the list

Tags: java, list, hashmap

My Code :

```
public List resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{
  ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
  int columns = md.getColumnCount();
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList(50);
  while (rs.next()){
     HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
     for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i){           
      row.put(md.getColumnName(i),rs.getObject(i));
     }
      list.add(row);
  }

return list;
}
```

So I am returning list which inturns having Key and Value pairs.In my Client logic I have to get the list and Compare the key value in each hashMap with the Text.

How can we do that ?Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you not manage to do? Do you want to get the column names? The values? To compare what with what?

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use the type parameters on the collection classes.  It will save you a lot of unnecessary casting.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the raw type `List`, **which you shouldn't use**, then you have to cast the row to a `HashMap<String,Object>`:

```
HashMap<String,Object> row = (HashMap<String,Object>) list.get(rowNum);
```

Then to get the columns names:

```
Set<String> columns = row.keySet();
```

And the values:

```
Object value = row.get(columnName);
```

**EDIT:** according to your comments, you seem to need one column to be the key and another column the value. So, when you create your `HashMap`, you should not use `getColumnName` as key but the value for that column instead:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(50);
while (rs.next()){
    HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
    row.put(rs.getObject(0),rs.getObject(1));
    list.add(row);
}
```

**WARNING: I don't know what you wanna do with this, but it is very weird, since you'll have only one key and one value in the `HashMap` for the row. You might want to use a single `HashMap` containing all rows instead (and get rid of the `List`):**

```
HashMap<String,String> table = new HashMap<String,String>();
while (rs.next()){
    table.put(rs.getString(0),rs.getString(1));
}
```

If you don't know in advance that the key will be in column 0 and the value will be in column 1, but you know the names of the columns, then you can loop through the columns to find the index of the one with the right name.

```
String keyColumnName = "FROM";
int keyColumnNum = -1; // to be found
for (int i = 0; i < md.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    if (keyColumnName.equals.getColumnName(i)) {
        keyColumnNum = i;
        break;
    }
}
// if the column exists, keyColumnNum has the right value here
```

Comment: I don't think he/she wants the key set.  I think he/she knows which key to look for, and is after the value.  So just doing a `get` on each `HashMap` should be enough.

Comment: In my previous method I am returning only list. So I am getting List for the client logic.So I have to get the hashmap key and value from List

Comment: @DavidWallace Yeah, I'm unsure what the OP wants exactly, hence my comment. I tried to answer what I understood of the question ^^

Comment: @user3496581 In my answer, I get everything from the list your client returned. Oh you mean you return the raw type, that's it?

Comment: @Joffrey I have one more doubt .If row.put(md.getColumnName(i),rs.getObject(i)); how it will be stored in Hashmap? Example My table has only two columns and have n rows .Column 1 =some string and column2= String .If I use  row.put(md.getColumnName(i),rs.getObject(i)); what will be there in the key and value inside the Hashmap.

Comment: @Joffrey As I mentioned above I need those two string values from Database and store it in hashmap. Can you please  guide me on how to get those values?  Thank you for the kind reply

Comment: The key will be the column name you gave with `md.getColumnName(i)` (from what you said it would be "some string"), the value will be the Object given by `rs.getObject(i)`. Are you asking how to use it later from outside the client method, not knowing the column names?

Comment: @Joffrey I need both key and Value as String which is in DB .Instead I am getting column name I need both string value in key value pairs

Comment: Oh, do you mean `keySet()` returns only keys, while you want key/value pairs? Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html you'll see you can use `entrySet()` instead.

Comment: @Joffrey I need both key and Value as String which is in DB .Instead I am getting column name I need both string value in key value pairs.Example I having a table called Email which has two columns and n rows.Column 1 NAME = FROM and colunm two NAME =TO .. Each rows has some string value in both from and to.I need to store the value of Column1 -FROM as Key and Column2-TO as value in hashmap

Comment: @user3496581 Ok that's a different story then. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @user3496581 WARNING: I don't know what you wanna do with this, but it is very weird, since you'll have only one key and one value in the HashMap for the row. You might want to use a single HashMap containing all rows instead (and get rid of the List)

Comment: @Joffrey                                                                                           HashMap<String,String> table = new HashMap<String,String>();
while (rs.next()){
    table.put(rs.getObject(0),rs.getObject(1));                       
} in the above code rs.getObject(0),rs.getObject(1) shows error since we defined Map as generics of <string , String> , If I will  give  rs.getString(0),rs.getString(1) what will happen?Is it fit string 0 to key and string 1 to value for each row in DB

Comment: You're right, use `getString` instead, I edited my post. The value of the first column (#0) will be the key, and the second (#1) will be the value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use raw type. Modify your code to something like that:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> resultSetToArrayList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    final ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();
    final List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(50);
    while (rs.next()) {
        final HashMap<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>(columns);
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; ++i) {
            row.put(md.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
        }
        list.add(row);
    }
    return list;
}
```

than you can access your list like that:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = yourObject.resultSetToArrayList(rs);
for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
    //you can call map.get("yourkey") here
}
```

Comment: I think you should use LinkedHashMap in order to keep the order the column and use Map to declare the variable like this:
Map<String, Object> row = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(columns);

Comment: @sendon1982 why would you use `Map` for the local variable instead of the concrete type?

Comment: Even if it is local variable, when using Spring Injection, it can be configured with different implementation, I think. It is just my opinion.

Comment: Well it's also shorter code I guess ^^ But since there used to be claims that interfaces calls were slower (without JIT at least), I took the habit of declaring concrete type for local variables.